# How to tell if an element is before another element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can you check if an element is before another element in DOM?

For example

```
<div>
    <div id='first'></div>
    <div id='second'></div>
</div>
<div id='third'></div>
```

`second` element is after `first` and before `third`. How can you check this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a jQuery funciton for this, however you can easily implement it by adding the following code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.isBeforeElement = function (elem) {
        if (typeof(elem) == "string") elem = $(elem); //just in case of bad input
        return this.add(elem).index(elem) > 0;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Afterwards you can call

```
$('#first').isBeforeElement($('#second')); //returns true
$('#second').isBeforeElement($('#third')); //returns false
$('#third').isBeforeElement($('#second')); //returns true
//etc..
```